# General error: 1364 Field doesn't have a default value after upgrade to 4.4 from low 3.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm currently working on finalizing an upgrade from CakePHP 3.3 to 4.4. I now have the same problem in a few places, which all are the same SQLSTATE error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'cert_request' doesn't have a default value`

The code looks currently like this:

### **Controller**

```php
$cert = $this->Certs->newEmptyEntity();
$data = $this->request->getData();

if(array_key_exists('certificate', $data) && !is_null($data['certificate'])) {
    $certificate = $data['certificate'];
    $cert_string = $certificate;
    $certificated = openssl_x509_parse($certificate);
} else {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data['effective_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($data['effective_date']));
        $data['expiry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($data['expiry_date']));

        $cert = $this->Certs->patchEntity($cert, $data);

        // Database Error happens here during save()
        if ($this->Certs->save($cert)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The cert has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);

        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The cert could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Mind, that `$data` does indeed not contain 'cert_request' and other fields related to this problem.

### **Model/Table**

```php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Certs Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Requests
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $CertTemplates
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $CertStatuses
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
 *
 * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
 */
class CertsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('certs');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('CertTemplates', [
            'foreignKey' => 'cert_template_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('CertStatuses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'cert_status_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('CertAlerts', [
            'foreignKey' => 'cert_id'
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): \Cake\Validation\Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyFor('id', Validator::EMPTY_ALL, Validator::WHEN_CREATE)
            ->add('id', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

        $validator
            ->dateTime('revocation_date')
            ->allowEmptyDatetime('revocation_date');

        $validator
            ->dateTime('effective_revocation_date')
            ->allowEmptyDatetime('effective_revocation_date');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('revocation_reason');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('common_name', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('common_name');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('cert_template_id', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('cert_template_id');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('requester_name', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('requester_name');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('requester_email', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('requester_email');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('budget_zi');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('billable');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('key_csr');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('cert_request');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('subject');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('alternative_name');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('serial_no');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('cert');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('ticket');

        $validator
            ->dateTime('request_submission_date')
            ->allowEmptyDatetime('request_submission_date');

        $validator
            ->dateTime('effective_date')
            ->requirePresence('effective_date', 'create')
            ->notEmptyDatetime('effective_date');

        $validator
            ->dateTime('expiry_date')
            ->requirePresence('expiry_date', 'create')
            ->notEmptyDatetime('expiry_date');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('country', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('country');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('organization', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('organization');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('organization_unit', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('organization_unit');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('city', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('city');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('state', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('state');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('issued_email');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('san');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('remarks');

       return $validator;
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['id']));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['cert_template_id'], 'CertTemplates'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['cert_status_id'], 'CertStatuses'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['cert_id'], 'CertAlerts'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Now I did add the following code which resolved the problem, but feels very much like a hack than an actual solution

```php
if (!array_key_exists('cert_request', $data)) { $data['cert_request'] = ''; }
if (!array_key_exists('ip_address', $data)) { $data['ip_address'] = ''; }
```

Now the fields do indeed not have a default value in the DB, but I think in the version which is currently in prod (PHP 5.4 and CakePHP 3.3) it just adds empty strings when the values are not present.

I've been reading through the migration notes and didn't find something that would explain why this behavior changed or perhaps it works differently.

There are parts that make it hard to debug (The application was developed on prod relying on external authentication which is not available locally), which is why I might've missed something. To be honest any idea what the problem could be would help.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just go ahead and add default values for these in the database schema?

Comment: @GregSchmidt That would be possible, but I would like to keep most things as is before I start the refactoring. Also I have not figured out why this was done this way in the first place and would hate to get unexpected results because of a change like this. On a side not it would also just be nice to know why it works on 5.4/3.3 and not on 8.2/4.4

Comment: I feel your pain. I had similar issues because mysql automatically converted such values to empty string and mariadb threw an error.
I think you should ALWAYS have default values in your database tables if you are not sure you have them always set when saving a new database record. You could also add the logic the set an empty value on "beforeSave" callback in your table model but solving this issue on the database level seems to me to be the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain. I had similar issues because mysql automatically converted such values to empty string and mariadb threw an error.

I think you should ALWAYS have **default values in your database tables** if you are not sure you have them always set when saving a new database record.

You could also add the logic the set an empty value on "beforeSave" callback in your table model
**but**
solving this issue on the database level seems to me to be the cleaner solution.

Comment: The part about MariaDB was quite useful! It seems like the previous Server used something else! Since it was decommissioned this week I only have the logs, but I'm sure it wasn't MariaDB.